# What is "MultiplicativeExpression" means?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading the EcmaScript6 specifications and in the Arithemetic operator section ( http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1 ) its mentioned like this

> AdditiveExpression :
>
> > MultiplicativeExpression
> >
> > AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression
> >
> > AdditiveExpression - MultiplicativeExpression

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 1):

An expression of multiplication or division.

See [Section 11.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN article on Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators):

> An *expression* is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.

So in this case a MultiplicativeExpression is any unit of code that results in multiplication. Most commonly it involves the `*` operator.

You can read the [Annotated EcmaScript](http://es5.github.io/x11.html#x11.6.1) as it contains some helpful links on top of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the ECMA specification is written in Martian. Or by Martians. Or for Martians. I've never been too sure, exactly.

Err, but more helpfully, section 11.6.1 explains how the "addition operator" (what we primitive humans usually call the plus sign or just "+" or "+/-") should treat the result of statements of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus division, and even string concatenation.

In the header you quote, the writers are calling attention to the various statement types they are trying to define, which is both the simple and more complex case of multiple statements that must be combined (as with the last two lines).

Later in the section it defines how 'hinting' should be handled, in what cases the script should treat variables as numbers instead of strings, etc.

It's just a really esoteric way to put it.

Comment: Agree .. I keep reading , reading .. to understand what it actually means .. I'm actually getting confused because of the word "MultiplicativeExpression" because in some other section, it defined as MultiplicativeExpression is an expression contains multiplication or division.

so if my arithmetic expression is just A + B + C  , why it is 

AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression

Comment: `A + B` is the additive expression. `A + B + C` is __AdditiveExpression + UnaryExpression__. AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is written to demonstrate order of operations, that you perform the multiplicative _before_ addition.

Comment: Great point @Mathletics, I had forgotten about order of operations.